# How can I analysis DVBS2 packets in Wireshark 3.4.6?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, dvb

I import [dvb-s2_bb_example.pcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=dvb-s2_bb_example.pcap) (which has been published by wireshark.org) in Wireshark 3.4.6. It is not interpreted correctly. I have enabled all protocols in Analyze->Enabled Protocols

By using Wireshark 1.10.0 it is interpreted correctly, but I want to use version 3.4.6.

How can I do it in 3.4.6 or the newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 3.4.6 version has a bug. I use a newer version (3.4.9) and it interprets my DVBS2 log correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the DVB-S2 over UDP heuristic dissector.  It used to be enabled with a preference for the protocol, but "enable heuristic dissector" preferences were removed and replaced with a single mechanism for enabling and disabling them at some point after the 1.10 release.

Open Analyze > Enabled Protocols, type "dab" into the search box, check the checkbox in front of "dvb_s2_udp", and clock "OK".

Comment: I did it. In [this picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tge5u7ld4bv83gp/Wireshark3.PNG?dl=0), you can see the setting in Wireshark 3.4.6, as you see it can't detect the protocol, but in [this picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r87q5adchpfqzy0/Wireshark1.PNG?dl=0), it is done correctly.

Comment: So in the second picture, what version of Wireshark is that?  And, in the first picture, had you clicked "OK", or had you just checked the check box?  The change won't take effect until you click "OK".

Comment: The second picture is about version 1.10. And about the second question ... . what do you think about me? :)) . Absolutely, I have clicked. If you see my question again, I don't have any problem with version 1.10, but I can't do it in version 3.4 or earlier.

Comment: Did you check the link I had imported in the question in your Wireshark?

Comment: Your capture worked for me with 3.4.9 when I enabled the dvb_s2_udp heuristic dissector.  Maybe 3.4.6 has a problem.